# mysql query to extractvalue from xml with wild search and iterate through the object to get the key & value

Tags: sql, mysql, extract-value

Example:

```
<Attributes>
   <Map>
     <entry key="Role_111">
       <value>
         <List>
           <String>07771</String>
         </List>
       </value>
     </entry>
     <entry key="Role_13">
       <value>
         <List>
           <String>07771</String>
         </List>
       </value>
     </entry>
     <entry key="Role_16">
       <value>
         <List>
           <String>07770</String>
           <String>07771</String>
         </List>
       </value>
     </entry>
     <entry key="Role_37">
       <value>
         <List>
           <String>07771</String>
         </List>
       </value>
     </entry>
     <entry key="Role_5">
       <value>
         <List>
           <String>07771</String>
         </List>
       </value>
     </entry>
     <entry key="isValid" value="true"/>
     <entry key="usercode" value="001"/>
   </Map>
 </Attributes>
```

In this xml, I have extract value of all roles for the user and print them to get the key and value separately. They should be in separate column and diffrent row entry for each  role.

I tried few ways to get the value but unable to do so, could anyone suggest how to get the values

I am able to get the value if I give the exact role but not all the roles and the value,

EXTRACTVALUE(s1.attributes, '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="Role_111"]/value/List/String') as role

EXTRACTVALUE(s1.attributes, '/Attributes/Map/entry/descendant::*') as role

Comment: Unfortunately, extractvalue is designed to return a single value, not multiple values. If there are multiple nodes matching the xpath selector, then those are still returned as a single space delimied string.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is taken from this: http://sql-debug.blogspot.com/2012/05/extractvalue-only-constant-xpath.html

If you try to build up the xpath expression dynamically, MySQL throws an error:

> Error Code: 1105. Only constant XPATH queries are supported

To work around this you can wrap [ExtractValue()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) in a [UDF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html):

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `ExVal`(ky text, xpath text) RETURNS text DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   RETURN CAST(ExtractValue(ky, xpath) AS CHAR);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This query is very inefficient but it works:

```sql
SELECT
    ExVal(s1.attributes, CONCAT('/Attributes/Map/entry[', r.n, ']/@key')) AS `role`,
    ExVal(s1.attributes, CONCAT('/Attributes/Map/entry[', r.n, ']/value/List/String[', v.n, ']')) AS `value`
FROM s1
JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
) r
JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
) v
HAVING `value` > '' AND `role` LIKE 'Role%';
```

Output:

| role | value |
| --- | --- |
| Role_111 | 07771 |
| Role_13 | 07771 |
| Role_16 | 07771 |
| Role_16 | 07770 |
| Role_37 | 07771 |
| Role_5 | 07771 |

The first derived table (`r`) is used for the indices for the `<entry>` elements, and the second derived table (`v`) for the `<String>` elements.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a1D6GjC2)

Comment: I tried the above query but got the below error in mysql 

Error Code: 1105. Only constant XPATH queries are supported

Comment: What MySQL version are you running (`select version();`)? Can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: 8.0.26 - this is the version

Comment: As you can see, it works fine in the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a1D6GjC2). Without being able to see what you have done, there is nothing I can suggest.